# Trying to make a face detector using python, but the code doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

I am trying to make a face detector using python, but the code doesn't seem to work

Here is my try,

```
import cv2
face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('face.xml')
img=cv2.imread('image.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.01, minNeighbors=5)
for x,y,w,h, in faces:
     img=cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow('face',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: please share what you expect from this code and specially what you get (error, warning, wrong results, nothing etc.)

Comment: You have to give the full path to the `CascadeClassifier` i.e. `C:\\..\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\face.xml`